# AngularJS - Directive not recognizing controller

Tags: angularjs

If I have a directive and a controller in the same file:

```
var app =  angular.module('app.navigation', []);

app.controller('NavItemCtrl', [ ....])

app.directive('navItem', [
        'ribbon', '$window', function (ribbon, $window) {
            return {
                require: ['^navigation', '^?navGroup'],
                restrict: 'AE',
                controller: 'NavItemCtrl',
      ...
      }])
```

Everything is fine, but if I move the controller code to a different file, because the current file is becoming too clutered, using the same module, and referencing the new controller file in my index page, the directive screams

```
          p0=NavItemCtrl&p1=not aNaNunction got undefined
```

My index page is like this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
  ....

 <script app.js ...>
 <script new controller file path .... >
 <script original directive file path .... >
  ....
 </body>
 </html>
```

What am I missing here?

**[Solution] Delta is right, I figured it out:**

For good housing keeping, I think it may be wise to have one JS file, listed as a dependency in the main app.js, that instantiates all the modules you will use, assuming your project is becoming large, and then reuse that instantiate w/o having any dependencies.

**As example:**

(1) Main App:

```
angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'app.SubApp1', 'app.SubApp2', 'app.SubApp3' ...]
```

(2) Then as a repository, if you will, create a new js file, say repositoryApp.js, instantiating these sub apps, making sure that this file is referenced before all other files that will use these sub app modules:

```
angular.module('app.SubApp1', [xxx]);
angular.module('app.SubApp2', [xxx]);
angular.module('app.SubApp3', [xxx]);
```

(3) Then when creating a series of directives, controllers, or whatever pertaining to a particular sub app, merely reference that sub app in the respective file as:

```
angular.module('app.SubApp1').controller('foo') .....
angular.module('app.SubApp1').directive('bar') .....
```

Without the dependency brackets as that is what threw the error for me.

Comment: can re-create the problem in a plunker?

Comment: When moving the controller to a different file, are you including the controller file after the first JS file in your index page?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctlu, I have the controllerJs file before the directive Js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your directive are you getting you app like this

```
var app =  angular.module('app.navigation');
```

if you put the brackets after it like your first example you will just be replacing what you have currently instead of getting it.

This get a new module

```
var app =  angular.module('app.navigation', []);
```

This gets an existing modules.

```
var app =  angular.module('app.navigation');
```

Notice the exclusion of the brackets in the second example.

Comment: I even went so far as this with no luck: angular.module('app.navigation', []).controller('xxxx) and angular.module('app.navigation', []).directive('xxxx')....

Comment: you cannot put the [] in the directive. that is replacing what you did with the controller.